# Python and Powershell passing arguments

Tags: python, powershell

I'm struggling with writing a Python/PowerShell script.
I have build a website in Django that takes input from the user then calls Python function that later is calling PowerShell script.
Everything works fine until I have to pass the argument with space to powershell.

Here's the code:

Python function

```
def getaduser_powershell(JsonParams):
    args = ['-ID_Param', JsonParams['id'],
        '-Domain_Param', JsonParams['domain'],
        '-AccountType_Param', JsonParams['accountType'],
        '-CreateOn_Param', JsonParams['createOn']
    ]
 
    fetchedUser = json.loads(subprocess.check_output([
        'powershell.exe',
        ('%s\\get-aduser.ps1') % script_path,
        *args
    ]))
 
    return fetchedUser
```

PowerShell function:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$ID_Param,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$Domain_Param,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$AccountType_Param,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$CreateOn_Param
)
 
try {
    $employee = Get-ADUser -Identity $ID_Param -Server $Domain_Param -Properties SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Title, Department, Company, C, Manager, EmployeeType
 
    $fetchedEmployee = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID = $employee.SamAccountName
        FirstName = $employee.GivenName
        LastName = $employee.Surname
        EmailAddress = $employee.EmailAddress
        Title = $employee.Title
        Department = $employee.Department
        Company = $employee.Company
        Country = $employee.C
        EmployeeType = $employee.EmployeeType
        Manager = $employee.Manager
        ManagerID = $null
        ManagerFirstName = $null
        ManagerLastName = $null
        Domain = $Domain_Param
        CreateOn = $CreateOn_Param
        AccountType = $AccountType_Param
    }
 
    if($null -ne $employee.Manager){
        $manager = Get-ADuser -Identity $employee.Manager -Server $Domain_Param -Properties DisplayName
        $fetchedEmployee.Manager = $manager.DisplayName
        $fetchedEmployee.ManagerID = $manager.SamAccountName
        $fetchedEmployee.ManagerFirstName = $manager.GivenName
        $fetchedEmployee.ManagerLastName = $manager.Surname
    }
 
 
    return $fetchedEmployee | ConvertTo-Json
 
}
catch {
    return $false | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Error message:

```
CalledProcessError at /NonPrimaryADAccounts/SecondaryMarket
Command '['powershell.exe', 'PathToScript\\powershell\\get-aduser.ps1', '-ID_Param', '0000000', '-Domain_Param', 'xxxxxx.xxx.xxx', '-AccountType_Param', 'Secondary Market', '-CreateOn_Param', 'xxxxxx.xxx.xxx']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Both functions are working just fine if I pass the -AccountType_Param with a string that does not contain a space.
I even thought of removing the spaces, but we have many users in AD that have Surname in two pieces so I still need to resolve it in one way or another.

I've tried to call the PowerShell function with a different approach but it's still giving me the same error message.
Here's example of what I've tried:

```
fetchedUser = json.loads(subprocess.check_output([
        'powershell.exe',
        ('%s\\get-aduser.ps1') % script_path,
        (-Domain Param '%s' -AccountType_Param '%s' -AccountType '%s' -CreateOn_Param '%s') % (JsonParams['id'], JsonParams['domain'], JsonParams['accountType'], JsonParams['createOn'])
    ]))
```

Unfortunately, I'm new to python so maybe there's just a simple trick that I'm not aware of.
Anyway, I'll be grateful for every tip! :)

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating your `AccountType_Param` string with double-quote characters? For example, `"\"{}\"".format(JsonParams['accountType'])` instead of `JsonParams['accountType']`.

Comment: I do not know of a solution but I strongly recommend sanitizing your JSON input if you plan on having this website public. Right now you can insert another "-" and input any parameter you want to powershell, and I think you see why that would be a bad idea

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this tip right but I just tried to call it like this:
"-AccountType_Param", JsonParams["accountType"]
and 
"-AccountType_Param", JsonParams['accountType']

But it gave the same error message :(

Okay, I see the edit, will try it ASAP

Comment: @Blupper It'll not be hosted to the public. It's just an experiment project for my team.

Comment: @PaulM. It worked!
So basically when I use `"\"{}\""` I'm telling that the input might have space?

Comment: @PatrykGołębiowski Glad it's working! In general, if you're attempting to submit command line arguments which contain spaces, you must encapsulate them with quotes, so that it is understood that the spaces are part of the argument, and are not interpreted as the start of a new token/argument.

Comment: @PaulM. Got it, kudos to you man! :)

Answer (score 0):

@PaluM. posted the answer in the comment:

```
"\"{}\"".format(JsonParams['accountType'])
```

Explanation:

> In general, if you're attempting to submit command line arguments
> which contain spaces, you must encapsulate them with quotes, so that
> it is understood that the spaces are part of the argument, and are not
> interpreted as the start of a new token/argument.